# Replace string in the list of string

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, replace

I want to replace the string `"$id"` with the next list item string. For example if the list is

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "test",
    "$id",
    "central",
};
```

then the list will become

```
"test"
"central"
"central"
```

Similarly if the list has only 1 item `"$id"` or `"$id"` is the last item in the list then it will not be replaced with anything.

I have created the following logic

```
 int index = list.FindIndex(x => x == "$id");
 if (index < list.Count()-1)
 {
    var newList = list.Select(x => x.Replace(list[index], list[index+1])).ToList();
    list = newList;
 }
```

Is this the right way of doing it or there is more efficient way of doing it.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What about scenario where collection has two `"$id"` one after another?

Comment: no there will be only 1 "$id" in the list @Fabio

Comment: In that case, it looks like you only need `list[index] = list[index + 1]` inside the `if` block. Also, use `list.IndexOf("$id")` instead of `FindIndex()` with a predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For collections with indexers(Array or List), you can do it in one loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && values[i - 1] == "$id")
    {
        values[i - 1] = values[i];
    }
}
```

For any type of collection you can use enumerator to "loop" the collection only once and have access to current and previous element.

Approach below supports multiple occurrences of `"$id"` as well.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReplaceTemplateWithNextValue(
    this IEnumerable<string> source, 
    string template
)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var previous = default(string);
        var replaceQty = 0;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (iterator.Current == "$id") replaceQty++;

            if (previous == "$id" && iterator.Current != "$id")
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < replaceQty; i++) yield return iterator.Current;
                replaceQty = 0;
            }

            if (iterator.Current != "$id") yield return iterator.Current;

            previous = iterator.Current;
        }

        if (previous == $"$id")
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < replaceQty; i++) yield return previous;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var list = new List<string>() { "test", "$id", "central" };

var replaced = list.ReplaceTemplateWithNextValue("$id");
// => { "test", "central", "central" }
```

Supported cases:

```
[Fact]
public void TestReplace()
{
    ReplaceId(Enumerable.Empty<string>()).Should().BeEmpty(); // Pass
    ReplaceId(new[] { "one", "two" })
        .Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] { "one", "two" }); // Pass
    ReplaceId(new[] { "$id", "two" })
        .Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] { "two", "two" }); // Pass
    ReplaceId(new[] { "one", "$id", "two" })
        .Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] { "one", "two", "two" }); // Pass
    ReplaceId(new[] { "one", "two", "$id" })
        .Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] { "one", "two", "$id" }); // Pass
    Replace(new[] { "one", "$id", "$id" })
        .Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] { "one", "$id", "$id" }); // Pass
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your comment on my answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity, sorry, you updated the question and I decided that comment become irrelevant.

Comment: I always feel like it makes it hard to understand the other comments. Now my reply to you is confusing.

Comment: @Enigmativity, so far I was under impression that here is an "unspoken" convention:  when you make some "low importance" comment about others code and they addressed that comment by updating the code - you just remove your own comment and they remove their.

Comment: I dislike needing to weed through past comments to see how I can keep them semantically valid. It's a big waste of time IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (provided that the list has at least one element):

```
list =
    list
        .Skip(1)
        .Zip(list, (x1, x0) => x0 == "$id" ? x1 : x0)
        .Append(list.Last())
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems simpler to me, but maybe doesn't work, or is slow?

```
int index = list.IndexOf("$id");
list.RemoveAt(index);
list.Insert(index, list[index]); //list[index] was list[index+1] before RemoveAt

// With error checks:
int index = list.IndexOf("$id");
if (index == -1) return; // or return error;
list.RemoveAt(index);
if (index >= list.Count-1) return;  // or return error;
list.Insert(index, list[index+1]);
```